# How to use a copy constructor to create a deep-copy of an Object array's contents without implementing cloneable() or arraycopy()?

Tags: java, copy-constructor

I need to create a copy of an array's contents, which are made up of various Objects of different types. However, I cannot use explicit casting to check the type of the Object, nor use the cloneable interface/arraycopy method.

To start, I created a superclass that all other classes extend from, but I'm not sure how I would go about using the specific classes' copy constructors. My initial attempt was:

```
public Building(Object obj) {
    try {
        this.windows= ((House)obj).windows; 
        this.basement = ((House)obj).basement; 
    } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
        this.windows = 0; 
        this.basement = false;
    }
    ... (various other try-catch blocks here)
}
```

With the driver being:

```
public static Building[] copyBuildings(Building[] objects) {

    Building[] objList = new Building[objects.length];
        
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {    
        objList[i] = new Building(objects[i]);
    }
        
    return objList; 
}
```

But, this doesn't properly call the subclass's copy constructor as I intended it to do, because it doesn't refer to them at all. I'm not sure how to continue.

Bearing in mind the lack of explicit typecasting, if I do not know the explicit type of an object during runtime, is it possible to call an Object's copy constructor (do I need to alter my current code)? or does polymorphism not function in this way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! (as well as general feedback, I'm not really used to using stackoverflow)

Comment: I don't see any array in the [pseudo] code in your question. Can you post a more concrete example? Something like a [mcve]?

Comment: @Abra Sorry about that! I added the current version I am using to (try and) call the copy constructor.

Comment: Maybe try [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you have a `Building[]` that contains various kinds of `Building` subtype.  And you want to create a deep copy.

You cannot do this by implementing a `Building` copy constructor.

Why?

Because a constructor for `Building` can *only* construct a `Building` instance.  It *cannot* construct a `House` instance ... or `Hotel` or a `Church` or ...

---

However, there are various alternatives that *will* work:

- Implement `Cloneable` in `Building` and each of its subtypes.
- Implement a *factory* method or class for creating a `Building` from another one.  Have it use `instanceof` (or Java 18+ pattern switches) to discriminate the subclasses and then use appropriate constructors for each subtype; e.g:

  ```
  if (building instanceof House) {
      return new House((House) building);
  } else if (building instanceof Hotel) {
      return new Hotel((Hotel) building);
  } else ...
  ```
- Use reflection.  It is complicated, but you don't need to write code for each individual class or subclass in the hierarchy.

Each alternative has pro's and con's, and we can't advise which one is best for each use-case.  Certainly, none of them are perfect for all use-cases.

Comment: Very detailed answer, I appreciate it. If I consider the restrictions that I cannot typecast anywhere (be it in the driver or in the Building class), import any foreign Classes, nor use the Cloneable interface. Would it still be possible?

Comment: No.  Not possible.  Even the reflection approach requires type casting, and switch patterns are a fancy form of `instanceof` + type cast.  (Though I guess it depends on exactly what you mean by "typecast"; i.e. whether you are talking about the syntax ... or what the syntax causes to happen.)

Comment: By typecast, I'm referring to syntax itself. I am restricted in finding the actual type of the object being copied. Though it is much clearer now thanks to you, I wasn't sure what sort of hidden solution there was (if any). Thanks again!